# mysql table having a->b and b->a values, select only a->b set of values

Tags: mysql

I have one table having 5 columns

> linkid, orinodeno, orinodeno, ternodeno, terifindex

linkid is autoincremented. orinodeno, oriifindex is one combination value and ternodeno, terifindex other combination (orinodeno,oriifindex is originating value and ternodeno,terifindex terminating value i.e, in between there is a link eg just like map two pts n in between connecting link) so my table contains `a->b` values (i.e a is combination of orinodeno, oriifindex and b is combination of ternodeno,terifindex) and b->a values. so I have to select only `a->b` set of values not `b->a`. Also sending my table image. [My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s4Vn.png)

Comment: not clear what you are asking for..?

Answer (score 0):

There is no a map definition in sql databases, forget it. Check any [database normalization tutorial](http://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization/). Then you shouldn't have any problems with select statements.

Answer (score 0):

**Please be clear about what you are asking. If you can not explain in words, please give example input and your expected output.**

From link of table image you have provided and description, It looks like you expect following:

Data in current table:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|linkid | orinodenumber | oriifindex | ternodenumber | terifindex|
------------------------------------------------------------------
|305    | 261           | 2          | 309           | 2         |
|306    | 309           | 2          | 261           | 2         |
|307    | 257           | 10         | 310           | 10        |
|308    | 310           | 10         | 257           | 10        |
|309    | 257           | 11         | 310           | 11        |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected Output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|linkid | orinodenumber | oriifindex | ternodenumber | terifindex|
------------------------------------------------------------------
|305    | 261           | 2          | 309           | 2         |
|307    | 257           | 10         | 310           | 10        |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If that is your case, following query might help you (Assuming table name as link_table):

```
SELECT *
FROM link_table o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT linkid 
              FROM link_table i 
              WHERE o.orinodenumber = i.ternodenumber 
              AND o.oriifindex = i.terifindex 
              AND o.linkid < i.linkid);
```